# Clear Memory After Using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, out-of-memory

I have a question.

I have an app which has 2 Activities. Both of them are ActionBarActivity.

When I start The Map activity like this:

```
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
```

After this in the map activty the map is loaded, everything's fine when I press the back button I call this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(MapsActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    mMap = null;
```

I have a problem there, because when I start the map activity I see that the allocated memory grows up to 120 MB from 30 MB... This is Ok. but when I finis the second Activity (The map activity) the allocated memory goes down only to 110 mb. so somewhere in the back I have 110 Mb of information which are not used. And because of this I am getting out Of memory exception on the first activity (When the first fragment loads a list view). What to do?

Please Help me :) thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3803). Since there is no map.destroy() function available, little can be done about it. However, as mentioned in the link, a workaround for this sort of problem is to re-use your Map instances in the future.

Since we're on the topic, here is another [link](http://www.curious-creature.com/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/comment-page-1/) regarding avoiding memory leaks in Android. Hope these links help shed some light on the issue.